# How invalidate other nodes besides that user node?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have this db:

```
db
 \
  users
   \
    $uid
     \
      email: "john@email.com"
     \
      username: "John"
```

I'm trying to not let the users to add other fields than `email` and `username`, so I have added:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        "email": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString()"
        },
        "username": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString()"
        },
        "$other": { ".validate": false } //Here!!!!!!!
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which works correct. What I also want to do, is to not allow the users to create other nodes within the `users` node other than the UID. So I have also added the above validation:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        "$other": { ".validate": false } //Works
      },
      "$other": { ".validate": false } //Doesn't work
    }
  }
}
```

But this operation fails:

> I get Error saving rules - Line 9: Cannot have multiple default rules ('$uid' and '$other').

So how to invalidate the addition of other nodes inside the `users` node, when using wild cards?

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Going forewward, please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the highest-level `$other` in your rules. Since you check `".write": "$uid === auth.uid",` inside the `$uid` node, users already can only write to their own node - and not create other sibling nodes of that.

So you'll want to use the rules as this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ...
        "$other": { ".validate": false }
      },
    }
  }
}
```